# How to get Excel cell color in dataset along with data VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to read the color and data of all Excel cells and display both in data grid view using data set.I am using the following code:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

 Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite7\Employees.xlsx;" &
                      Dim oledbConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        Try

            oledbConn.Open()
            Console.WriteLine("conneection opeened")

            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", oledbConn)

            Dim oleda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
                oleda.SelectCommand = cmd
                      Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
                oleda.Fill(ds)
                             gvEmployees.DataSource = ds
                    gvEmployees.DataBind()
        Catch e1 As Exception
                         Console.WriteLine(e1.Message)
            Finally
                            oledbConn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
    Public Function colorchange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) As Object
        Dim excel_app As New Excel.ApplicationClass()
        Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook =
excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite7\Employees.xlsx")
                    Dim sheet = workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
                  Dim colorindex As Integer
            colorindex = sheet.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
             MsgBox(colorindex)
            Return colorindex
    End Function
```

In default.aspx page:

```
 <div style ="height:600px; width:100%; overflow:auto;">
        <asp:GridView HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  AutoGenerateColumns ="True"  Width="100%" ID="gvEmployees" runat="server" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="colorchange">
            </asp:GridView>
```

I want to read all cell color and display in data grid view,but this code does not displays anything.

Comment: Is it necessary or better to use OLEDB to open an Excel file? I think you need Office API anyway... Is it because you want to avoid reading data in loops? Irrespective to that, I think you will need 1 dataset for data and 1 dataset (or List (of), etc.) for BackColors. Either read background color for each cell in the range, or make a list of cell adresses with colors found. Then you will loop through or use the cell addresses and set BackColor like DataGridView1.rows(ir).cells(ic).Style.BackColor =  Color.AliceBlue, where the color can be of course also defined from RGB or else.

Comment: salsinga please look at your snippet code, it's not properly aligned (everything is messed up). I'm afraid I don't understand why you complained about me trying to align it for you? Nevertheless in short the problem is that you cannot read any style/formatting in an excel file with OLEDB, you can only read and write cells value with it. In order to read cells background color you'll have to use another approach, for example Excel Interop, or better yet Open XML SDK.